Spring Webflux and authentication: sessions or tokens?
I am building a Java Spring Webflux based application and after reading a lot about what is the best for the authentication layer, I still haven't come to a conclusion.
A lot of people doesn't like the usage of JWT tokens for emulating sessions even if they are stateful. But I've also read these reactive applications are meant to be authenticated/authorized using tokens.
I haven't found any samples in the official Spring doc related to session creation and management so I think this is not the preferred option...
Any ideas that may help unblocking myself?
Thanks!
I haven't found any samples in the official Spring doc related to session creation and management so I think this is not the preferred option...

You didn't find it probably because it's a part of J2EE, ex https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html But anyway, Spring has additional stuff for sessions at https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/index.html

But I've also read these reactive applications are meant to be authenticated/authorized using tokens this statement is not true, authentication is completely seperate from what type of server technology you can use

I haven't found any samples in the official Spring doc related to session creation and management so I think this is not the preferred option its because you dont create the session, thats what spring security does for you as a framework. You should be looking at athentication types, like basic login, formlogin, saml, oauth2
